# How to Write body in POST() in R Using "httr" Package

Tags: r, api, httr

I got stuck figuring out the proper usage of POST in package "httr". I use this as following.

```
getdata <- POST(url=url,add_headers(`Content-Type`="application/json"),
            body=list(user="xxx",password="xxx"))
```

The result is not right as it should be. I didn't good examples from the internet.

Even after I remove "add_headers", it is still not right.

```
getdata <- POST(url=url,body=list(user="xxx",password="xxx"))
```

The result is as following:

```
fromJSON(content(getdata,type="text"))
```

$success
[1] FALSE

BTW, can I add add_headers in POST? Thank you in advance.

Thank you guys. I found out the solution for my situation anyway.

Body can be in character format which is much easier than using the list format.

Comment: You say the result is "not right," but what exactly is the right result? I don't see a way to help you with the information you provided.

Comment: Hi Mr. Flick.  So the right form should be like this: { "token": "xxx"   "user": "xxx"     "success": true} which is from the Advanced Rest Client.

Comment: I agree to MrFlick: it's prly impossible to debug without having a reproducible example (maybe you need to add more to the body of the request? Who knows...)

Comment: You need encode = "json"

Comment: Thank you Hadley, that's a good point!